# I got a low quality image when converting sRGB to CMYK in PHP using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I am getting a low quality image while trying to convert from sRGB to CMYK in PHP using Imagick.

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Converted Image
[image: Converted Image]

And here is my PHP code:

```
$i = new \Imagick();
$i->clear();
$i->readimage("original_image.jpg");

$icc_cmyk = file_get_contents('/tmp/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc'); 
$i->profileimage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
unset($icc_cmyk);

$i->transformImageColorspace(12);
$i->writeImage('converted_image.php');
```

I couldn't figure out why this is happen.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you say what version of ImageMagick is on your system, and probably try upgrading to the latest one. What you're seeing is just weird, and possibly a bug. I can't reproduce it in a current version of Imagick/ImageMagick. I think I remember seeing someone complain of something similar, but can't find it.

Comment: Your're right. I was using the ImageMagick version 6.7.7.10. Then, I upgraded to version 6.9.2-7 and now the converted image is perfect. Please post that as an answer so that I can accept as the correct solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several bugs related to CMYK in the older versions of ImageMagick.

According to the [changelog](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) there was something fixed for 6.8.2-4 which might be related to what you are seeing.

Upgrading to the latest version of ImageMagick, when you see bad an unexpected output from image conversion is usually worth trying to see if that eliminates the problem.